# ASP.NET RC2 - ModelState doesn't validate elements of collection

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, modelstate

Let's say that I have simple model with required attribute above property.

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    string Name {get;set;}
    string Surname {get;set;}
}
```

When I POST/PUT only one instance of User and Name is empty it works pretty well. ModelState is not valid and contains error.

When I POST/PUT collection of objects User and in some of them Name is empty then ModelState is valid and it does not contain any validation errors.

Could you tell me what is wrong with it and why it concerns only collections? I noticed same behaviour when I have one object with relation one-many. Then collection within this object also is not validated by ModelState.

I don't want to validate required fields manually, it should work automatically.

Comment: Validation is property-level, there is a workaround that you can put the collection into a model as a property.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a ActionFilter

```
public class ModelStateValidActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // Validate ICollection
        if (context.ActionArguments.Count == 1 && context.ActionArguments.First().Value.GetType().IsListType())
        {
            foreach (var arg in (IList)context.ActionArguments.First().Value  )
            {
                var parameters = arg.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    var argument = context.ActionArguments.GetOrDefault(parameter.Name);
                    EvaluateValidationAttributes(parameter, argument, context.ModelState);
                }
            }
        }

        if (context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return next();
        }
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void EvaluateValidationAttributes(PropertyInfo parameter, object argument, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var validationAttributes = parameter.CustomAttributes;
        foreach (var attributeData in validationAttributes)
        {
            var attributeInstance = parameter.GetCustomAttribute(attributeData.AttributeType);
            var validationAttribute = attributeInstance as ValidationAttribute;
            if (validationAttribute != null)
            {
                var isValid = validationAttribute.IsValid(argument);
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    modelState.AddModelError(parameter.Name, validationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(parameter.Name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and add it into your MVC options

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddMvcOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.Filters.Add(new ModelStateValidActionFilter());
    }
```

Comment: how does this solve the problem of validating the collection ?

Comment: If the collection is a property, you can implement IValidatableObject to validate it, but it seems there is no way to validate a root collection. Validation only applies to 'property-level' attributes.

Comment: I can't believe that it doesn't work automatically. If we have nested model e.g.User which has an Address as property and Addres has empty required property we will get an error. There must be something with collections...

Comment: yes. it does not work automatically by ModelState.IsValid, but you can still make it work with ActionFilter, which gives you possibility to do extra validations. I updated my answer, you may need to polish the code, but it is a solution to make it possible, and you can also validate query strings in same way. Another advantage with ValidationActionFilter is you can remove all ModelState.IsValid from all controllers. I don't know who did the unvote and why, please vote it back.